# ImportError: cannot import name mpl (from matplotlib import mpl)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, importerror

I am trying to run a code that I wrote a couple of years ago that uses `mpl` from `matplotlib`. It used to run fine, but now suddently it's throwing an error:

```
from matplotlib import mpl
ImportError: cannot import name mpl
```

I am using Python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.5.2.

Comment: matplotlib does not have any submodule or function called `mpl`. I highly doubt that this has ever been different. In any case, why would you like to import a nonexisting module? Just remove that line.

Comment: I think you are right. I am not sure why I had it like shown in the code. I searched around for a bit before asking here, and I just couldn't find anything that helped. What made it confusing was that I know I never messed with the code since it worked the last time... :-/

Comment: So, if you remove the line, everything works as expected, or not?

Comment: So, I just change to `import matplotlib as mpl`, where I use it as `mpl.colors.ListedColormap()`. Didn't throw any error like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

---

It really did work in earlier versions but it was first deprecated (in version [1.3](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#changes-in-1-3-1)):

> The `mpl` module is now deprecated. Those who relied on this module should transition to simply using `import matplotlib as mpl`.

and then removed (in version [1.5.0](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#changes-in-1-5-0)):

> Remove the module `matplotlib.mpl`. Deprecated in 1.3 by PR #1670 and commit 78ce67d161625833cacff23cfe5d74920248c5b2

Comment: I had it written as `from matplotlib import mpl, pyplot as plt` earlier. It did run earlier like this though..

Comment: @user11 I updated the answer. They simply removed the submodule (for matplotlib >= 1.5) in favor of `import matplotlib as mpl`. :)

Comment: That's helpful to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you cannot import "mpl" from matlotlib because it doesn't exist.
I guess you want to try to import matplotlib AS mpl. You should try this :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to that and it worked. It's just that they have removed as figured out by the answer I accepted.

Comment: how do I import pyplot?